# Make a 2d array list object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, initialization

I am trying to make a 2d subclass of the `list` object called map2d. I want to be able to initialize `map2d` and get a 2d array of a defined size.

**E.g,**

```
class map2d(list):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        # Magic code that makes this work

 Map = map2d(3,2)
 print(Map)
```

**Output**

```
[[None, None], [None,None], [None,None]]
```

**What I Tried**

```
class map2d(list):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self = [[None for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]
```

I know that this is probably a perversion of everything sacred but it makes sense to me.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: @JhonAZ1 what is your problem?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I just get an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical about `self`. When you assign anything to `self`, e.g. `self = whatever` that works how assignment always works in Python: now `self` refers to whatever object `whatever` referred to. Assignment never mutates. You need to use mutator methods, like `.append` or `.extend` or index/slice based assignment. Here's a simple way:

```
In [1]: class map2d(list):
   ...:     def __init__(self,x,y):
   ...:         for _ in range(x):
   ...:             r = []
   ...:             self.append(r)
   ...:             for _ in range(y):
   ...:                 r.append(None)
   ...:

In [2]: map2d(2,3)
Out[2]: [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

However, I see no good reason to use inheritance for this. Just create a helper function:

```
In [3]: def map2d(x,y):
   ...:     return [[None for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]
   ...:

In [4]: map2d(2,3)
Out[4]: [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Note a list is not an array, and lists don't have "dimensions", they only have a length.

If you really want to prevent negative indexing, you could do:

```
In [10]: class MyList(list):
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, item):
    ...:         if isinstance(item, int) and item < 0:
    ...:             raise TypeError("MyList indices must be positive")
    ...:         self.__getitem__(item)
    ...:

In [11]: x = MyList()

In [12]: x.append(3)

In [13]: x[-1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c30dd0d358dc> in <module>()
----> 1 x[-1]

<ipython-input-10-f2169a236374> in __getitem__(self, item)
      2     def __getitem__(self, item):
      3         if isinstance(item, int) and item < 0:
----> 4             raise TypeError("MyList indices must be positive")
      5         self.__getitem(item)
      6

TypeError: MyList indices must be positive
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I wanted an object is so that I could prevent negative indexing.

Comment: @JohnAZ1 a `list` *already is an object*. **everything is an object** in Python. If you wanted to subclass to prevent negative indexing, you need to override `__getitem__` not `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just creating a list within a list, there is no need to use classes:

```
def map2d(x, y):
    return [[None for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]

print(map2d(3, 2)) # [[None, None], [None,None], [None,None]]
```

This will give you the desired output.

Also, note that if you are looking to customize the way a class is printed, you should use the method `__str__`, eg:

```
class Example:
    def __str__(self):
        return "Example Class Object"

print(Example()) # Example Class Object
```

Comment: The reason I want to use a class is so that I can prevent negative indexing and it seemed nice to be able to put all of this together

Comment: Then you should checkout the answer from @juanpa.arrivillaga :)